# Using the modal verb WILL

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, future-tense

I have come across the following sentences in an upper-intermediate book:

1. Living in a foreign country seems strange at first, but you **soon** get used to it.
2. Don't worry. You **will soon** get used to it.

As far as I - as a non-native speaker- remember, only the first sentence can be true. 
Is there a possibility for the second one to be grammatically acceptable as well?

If yes, would there be any difference(s) in meaning of them?

Answer (score 2):

Both are acceptable. There is a difference in meaning, and that difference is tense.

The word "soon" is an adverb, it is modifying the verb phrase "get used to", by telling us when it happens.

The first is describing a fact. It is using the simple present to that this is always true.

> Everybody who moves to a foreign country gets used to it soon after arriving.

The second is making a prediction about the future. It uses the "will" future to predict what will happen

> You will have moved to a foreign country recently. You will get used to it soon after arriving.

The first claims a general fact, the second makes a future prediction.  The adverb "soon" can be used in both cases.